# Como imprimir el nombre de los pacientes registrados?

Tags: java, string, bucles

Este código me pregunta el numero de pacientes a registrar y me pide capturar el nombre de cada uno, como puedo imprimir cada uno de los nombre registrados?, me piden no usar arreglo y apenas estoy aprendiendo a programar.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int cantUsuarios, i;
    String nombre; 
    Scanner pideNum = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Cantidad de personas a registrar");
    cantUsuarios = pideNum.nextInt();

    if (cantUsuarios>5) //valida que sean sólo 5 registros
    System.out.println("Sólo se admite un registro máximo de 5 personas");
    else
        for (i=1;i<=cantUsuarios;i++){
        System.out.println("Teclee nombre del paciente");
        Scanner pideNom = new Scanner(System.in);
        nombre = pideNom.nextLine();   
        
    }
   
 }
```

}

Comment: Hola buen día, lo que puedes hacer es imprimir enseguida de que lo lees: System.out.println("Nombre: " + nombre);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola en vista de que dices tu que los nombres no deben ser agregados a un array, pues aqui te traigo una solucion, nota: vi que tenias un objeto scanner para capturar la cantidad y otra para el nombre del paciente puedes usar el mismo objeto scanner dentro del mismo metodo para capturar cualquier dato, aqui te dejo el codigo espero te ayude y te sirva.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int cantUsuarios, i;
    String nombre;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);// puedes usar el mismo scanner para solicitar cualquier dato, no es
                                            // necesario crear dos como tenias.

    do {
        System.out.print("Cantidad de personas a registrar: ");
        cantUsuarios = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
    } while (cantUsuarios > 5);

    for (i = 0; i < cantUsuarios; i++) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese el nombre del paciente: ");
        nombre = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println((i + 1) + ". NOMBRE: " + nombre);

    }

}
```

Comment: Como dice Garduño los puedes imprimir directamente.

Y  un par de mejoras:

No sería necesario que en cada iteración instancies un nuevo Scanner para leer cada nombre, lo puedes declarar arriba, debajo del pideNum, y luego ya sin mas en cada iteración como tienes, nombre = pideNom.nextLine(). Por otro lado si el usuario introduce una cantUsuarios > 5, el programa finalizaría, y no le estás dando la posibilidad al usuario a corregir o introducir otra cantidad correcta, y tampoco podría introducir ningún nombre. Estaría bien que pudiera presentar esa lógica.